# strange behavior with addElicitSlotDirective

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, alexa-slot

Something strange is happening in my skill.

I isolated the error into a different skill.

**The skill id:** amzn1.ask.skill.6918614f-1f20-4ea3-bad4-b2284a296938

In the skill, I have one intent- HelloWorldIntent.

*The intent has 2 slots-* lala and bibi.

The default prompts for each one of them(the prompts that been called when Alexa doesn't find a proper value for the slot in the user reply) are:

lala- sorry, I didn't get that. what is the value of lala?

bibi- bibibibbb

*****the auto delegation interface is on**

I have an addElicitSlot action in LaunchRequestHandler for lala slot,

and in HelloWorldIntentHandler for bibi slot.

However, when I tried to give a value to lala,

I get the default prompt of bibi.

**The interaction model-**

```
{
"interactionModel": {
    "languageModel": {
        "invocationName": "check it",
        "modelConfiguration": {
            "fallbackIntentSensitivity": {
                "level": "LOW"
            }
        },
        "intents": [
            {
                "name": "AMAZON.CancelIntent",
                "samples": []
            },
            {
                "name": "AMAZON.HelpIntent",
                "samples": []
            },
            {
                "name": "AMAZON.StopIntent",
                "samples": []
            },
            {
                "name": "HelloWorldIntent",
                "slots": [
                    {
                        "name": "lala",
                        "type": "AMAZON.SearchQuery"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "bibi",
                        "type": "AMAZON.SearchQuery"
                    }
                ],
                "samples": [
                    "hello {lala}",
                    "ya {bibi}"
                ]
            },
            {
                "name": "AMAZON.NavigateHomeIntent",
                "samples": []
            },
            {
                "name": "AMAZON.FallbackIntent",
                "samples": []
            }
        ],
        "types": []
    },
    "dialog": {
        "intents": [
            {
                "name": "HelloWorldIntent",
                "confirmationRequired": false,
                "prompts": {},
                "slots": [
                    {
                        "name": "lala",
                        "type": "AMAZON.SearchQuery",
                        "confirmationRequired": false,
                        "elicitationRequired": true,
                        "prompts": {
                            "elicitation": "Elicit.Slot.716071660021.1504772685502"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "bibi",
                        "type": "AMAZON.SearchQuery",
                        "confirmationRequired": false,
                        "elicitationRequired": true,
                        "prompts": {
                            "elicitation": "Elicit.Slot.1152666376659.1399331737295"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
        "delegationStrategy": "ALWAYS"
    },
    "prompts": [
        {
            "id": "Elicit.Slot.716071660021.1504772685502",
            "variations": [
                {
                    "type": "PlainText",
                    "value": "sorry, i didnt get that. what is the value of lala?"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": "Elicit.Slot.1152666376659.1399331737295",
            "variations": [
                {
                    "type": "PlainText",
                    "value": "bibibibbb"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

**The code-**

```
const LaunchRequestHandler = {
canHandle(handlerInput) {
    return Alexa.getRequestType(handlerInput.requestEnvelope) === 'LaunchRequest';
},
handle(handlerInput) {
    const speakOutput = handlerInput.t('WELCOME_MSG');

    return handlerInput.responseBuilder
        .speak(speakOutput)
        .reprompt(speakOutput)
        .addElicitSlotDirective('lala', {
                name: 'ChallengeIntent',
                confirmationStatus: 'NONE',
                slots: {}
        })
        .getResponse();
}
```

};

```
const HelloWorldIntentHandler = {
    canHandle(handlerInput) {
        return Alexa.getRequestType(handlerInput.requestEnvelope) === 'IntentRequest'
            && Alexa.getIntentName(handlerInput.requestEnvelope) === 'HelloWorldIntent';
    },
    handle(handlerInput) {
        const lala=Alexa.getSlotValue(handlerInput.requestEnvelope, 'lala')
        const speakOutput =`yay the value is ${lala}`;

        return handlerInput.responseBuilder
            .speak(speakOutput)
            .addElicitSlotDirective('bibi', {
                name: 'ChallengeIntent',
                confirmationStatus: 'NONE',
                slots: {}
        })
            //.reprompt('add a reprompt if you want to keep the session open for the user to respond')
            .getResponse();
    }
};
```

[the test in Alexa console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ypmg.png)

I'm very frustrated, please help me:(

I need to submit my work until the end of August.

Tnx:)

Answer (score 0):

Is it because you are resetting the intent when you pass a new intent object to addElicitSlotDirective ?  Try passing the existing intent.

```
handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.intent
        .speak(speakOutput)
        .addElicitSlotDirective('bibi', handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.intent)
```